# my do while loop cant break. i dont know whats wrong? when type && it will break but not if i type ||

Tags: c#, loops

im new to c#. I'm trying to make a dice game really basic.

my do while loop cant break right. i dont understand what's wrong. if i type && in my while loop, it will break but first when both int is 0. i need it to break when one of my int is 0. right now i've type || and it wont break at all

```
while ((liv >= 0) || (mitLiv >= 0));

static void Main(string[] args) {
        
        int liv; //monsterets liv
        int mitLiv; //dit liv
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("Velkommen til monster terning spil. du vinder spillet ved at dræbe monsteret.");
        Console.WriteLine("Indtast hvor mange liv monsteret skal have");

        liv = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // her læser den monsterets liv
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("hvor mange liv skal du have?");

        mitLiv = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); // her læser den mit liv
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("du har givet monsteret {0} liv og dig selv {1} i liv", liv, mitLiv);
        Console.WriteLine("tryk på en knap for at komme videre");
        Console.ReadKey();
        Console.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine("tryk på en knap for at slå med terningen");//spillet går igang
        Console.ReadKey();

        do {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int dice = rnd.Next(1, 7); //den generer et random tal mellem 1-6

            if (dice == 1) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("du slog {0}. Critical hit! monster slår 2 gange", dice);
                Console.WriteLine("dit liv er " + (mitLiv - 2));
                Console.WriteLine("tryk på en knap for at slå igen");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            if (dice == 2) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("du slog {0} monsteret slog tilbage", dice);
                Console.WriteLine("du har mistet et liv. dit liv er " + --mitLiv);
                Console.WriteLine("tryk på en knap for at slå igen");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

                if (dice == 3) {//hvis tallet er 2 eller 3 gør følgende
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("du slog {0} monsteret slog tilbage", dice);
                Console.WriteLine("du har mistet et liv. dit liv er " + --mitLiv);
                Console.WriteLine("tryk på en knap for at slå igen");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            
            if (dice == 4) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("du slog {0} du ramte monsteret 1 gang", dice);
                Console.WriteLine("monsterets liv er nu " + --liv);
                Console.WriteLine("tryk på en knap for at slå igen");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

            if (dice == 5) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("du slog {0} du ramte monsteret 1 gang", dice);
                Console.WriteLine("monsterets liv er nu " + --liv);
                Console.WriteLine("tryk på en knap for at slå igen");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            if (dice == 6) {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("du slog {0} Critical Hit! du slog monsteret 2 gange", dice);
                Console.WriteLine("monsterets liv er nu " + (liv - 2));
                Console.WriteLine("tryk på en knap for at slå igen");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }


        }
        while ((liv >= 0) || (mitLiv >= 0));  // hvis monsterets liv eller mit liv bliver 0 gør følgende*/

        if (liv >= 0) {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("Du har vundet!! monsteret er død :)");
        }
        if (mitLiv >= 0) { 
            Console.Clear();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            Console.WriteLine("du har desværre tabt! :(");
        }


    }
}
}
```

Comment: yeah. but when i type || it doesnt break at all. and when i type && it cant break right. but break it will

Comment: Maybe you meant `while(liv > 0 && mitLiv > 0)` this will break as soon as one of them reaches 0 (the meaning is *"keep going as long as both are >0"*). Also note that if for some reason you only get 1s and 6s, you'll never break out of your loop, as you don't decrement anything

Comment: something is wrong, i dont know if its everything, but it cannot break right

Comment: As @Rafalon noticed, "i need it to break when one of my int is 0" means "i need it to continue when *both* of my ints are != 0". So "&&" is correct.

Comment: i've typed in my codes when it hits 1 and 6 my int will -2. agian im new, so i dont know if its wrong to type it like that.

Comment: it can also be -1. Because you gonna do 2 in dmg, when the dice shows 1 or 6

Comment: i just think i've made a broken game. cant be fixed

Comment: `mitLiv - 2` this doesn't change the value of `mitLiv` (when `--mitLiv` does change its value). Also, you are recreating a `new Random()` at every loop, you should move that part up (outside the loop)

Comment: Just to complete Rafalons answer, instead of `mitLiv - 2`, you have to use `mitLiv-=2`. Anyway, I think it is more readable if all calculations over `mitLiv`and `liv` are done in a separated line outside the display string composition ( `liv - =2; 
 Console.WriteLine("monsterets liv er nu " + liv );` )

Comment: sorry for late reply. But thank you so much on the *liv -= 2* i struggled with that also! :) you fixed my game! 
the reason i put my new random outside the loop is, if the dice show 4, it will rool 4 every time. but when i put it in my loop, its random or randomish

Comment: its actually dice game. i need to kill the monster before it kills me, so i need to roll the dice. and when it shows 4 it will do something and it show 6 it will do something etc.. it works now and im glad, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There's at least 2 errors in your code.

First when you do that: `(liv - 2)` you're not decrementing a thing. You have to do `liv -= 2` or `liv = liv -2`. Same in mitLiv.

And you can't change && for || once you want to continue until one of both are >= 0